# React app reloads on multiple async image downloads

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch, azure-blob-storage

Running a react app in node, created from create-react-app, I have a proxy node server running where I have an API setup to download images from azure blob storage. The problem is whenever I make multiple calls in a row to /api/downloadimage from within react, the page reloads, as if react gives up on the render and loses the state of the app. The images do in fact download, but the app refreshes. The problem doesn't happen when I only make the call once.

Nodemon is running server.js. Tried telling nodemon to ignore changes to the directory where the images are downloaded to, seemed to have no effect.

Within node:

```
app.get('/api/downloadplateimage', function(req, res, next) {
  const plateName = req.query.name;
  downloadPlate(plateName)
    .then(response => {
        res.json(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        res.json({ success: false });
    });
});

const downloadPlate = (blobName) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    blobService.getBlobToLocalFile(platesContainer, blobName, imagesDir + '/plates/' + blobName, err => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve({ success: true });
        }
    });
  });
};
```

Within react:

```
componentDidMount() {
  Promise.all([
    this._downloadImage('<guid>.jpeg'),
    this._downloadImage('<guid>.jpeg')
  ]).then(res => {
    console.log('fetched images');
  });
}

_downloadImage = (imageName) => {
  return fetch(`/api/downloadplateimage?name=${imageName}`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(body => {
      let imageAvailable = false;
      if (body.success) {
        imageAvailable = true;
      }
      ...
      this.setState({imageAvailable});
  });
}
```

Comment: when you say _"the page reloads"_ do you mean like an actual page load? (like if you press F5)

Comment: @Sagivb.g yeah, like F5

Comment: That's interesting, can you reproduce it without the fetch? i mean do a `Promise.All`  but just return a new promise for each

Comment: @Sagivb.g  Tried with just promises, can't reproduce without the fetch

Comment: I've tried doing the same with `fetch`, can't reproduce it.

Comment: @1Canuck16, are you sure is not just a flick? If you open your console, does it refresh the data too?

Comment: @Tico yeah it refreshes the console too

Comment: That's interesting, I'll be watching. up

Comment: by the way, shouldn't you return the response after `this.setState({imageAvailable});` ?

Comment: @Sagivb.g has no effect. my 'response' is if imageAvailable becomes true

Comment: not related to your issue, but if you are not returning anything, then you'll get `undefined` inside `Promise.all`

Comment: @Sagivb.g yeah, same refresh issue occurs if I do return after setting state.

Comment: @1Canuck16 there's no `window.location.reload()` anywhere? That's very weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up giving up on downloading the blobs and using the URLs  off of Azure for the img src(s) instead.